# What is needed to have installed in Raspbian to debug a Xamarin.IoT application?

Tags: xamarin.iot

I want to give a test to the new Xamarin.IoT framework but can't find the previous requeriments (packages) to be installed on Raspbian.

I will appreacite your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fresh installation of Raspbian, you don't need any Xamarin/Mono related package (software) to run/debug a Xamarin.IoT application.

Keep in mind that Visual Studio connects to the raspberry using SSH, so it's needed to enable it in the raspberry.

To do that just simple use the raspi-config utility, open a terminal and execute

> sudo raspi-config

And go to **Interfacing Options -> SSH**

Maybe it would be also helpful to install a VNC service that allows you to view remotely the screen (desktop) of your raspberry, in case you dont have an external display

You can also install it using raspi-config

**Interfacing Options -> VNC**

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Addin can be downloaded/installed from the Extension Gallery, it only needs your Raspberry with SSH service enabled.

This deploys a bundle version of Mono (4.6) runtime ready to use  in Raspbian for your device.

Also you can also install newer versions using apt-get (I recommend this way) .. the addin will choose always the newest version. You can do it using this guide:
http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-raspbian

Once installed you are to select 'Console application' template from the IoT section (if you can’t see this section probably you have not installed the addin).

This project works like a normal console application, but it has a explorer to select in what device you wan’t to deploy your application.

Add a Break point in your code and Run Debug in your VS to check that everything works correctly.

One of magic of this, is you can create a wrapper to use any linux shared library (.so) with C#  http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#linux-shared-library-search-path

I recommend try the examples here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-iot-samples

Also I created an abstraction library in the top of Raspberry.IO to make more natural work with components.

https://github.com/netonjm/IoTSharp.Components

And to finish if you are interested in HomeKit try this library to create virtual accessories :

https://github.com/netonjm/HapSharp